# Cannot use function in a form react js

Tags: reactjs

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.submitQA = this.submitQA.bind(this);
  this.onSearchChange = this.onSearchChange.bind(this);
  this.isSearched = this.isSearched.bind(this);
  this.answerSubmitted = this.answerSubmitted.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    answers: [],
    answer: '',
    searchTerm: '',
  }
}

answerSubmitted(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 const input = event.target.querySelector('input');
 const value = input.value;
 const updatedList = this.state.answer;
 updatedList.push(value);
 this.setState({ answer: updatedList });
}



 render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="center">

        <form >
          Search:  <input type="text" onChange={this.onSearchChange}  /><br/>
        </form>

        <form onSubmit={this.submitQA}>
          Q & A:
          <input type="text" placeholder=" Course/Q/A"/>
          <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
        </form>
          <span>{basicFormat}</span>
      </div>

{ this.state.answers.filter(this.isSearched(this.state.searchTerm)).map(function(item) {
return (
    <div>
      <form >
        <text> {item} </text>
        <input onSubmit={this.answerSubmitted} type="text" placeholder="answer the question"/>
      </form>
    </div>
)
  }
    )
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why cant I use the function here? Error: Cannot read property 'answerSubmitted' of undefined. Not really sure why this is happening have tried searching around but all I could find is that people did not bind their method which I have done. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you pass to `map` changes the `this` context. Use an arrow function instead:

```
{this.state.answers.filter(this.isSearched(this.state.searchTerm)).map((item) => (
  <div>
    <form>
      <text> {item} </text>
      <input onSubmit={this.answerSubmitted} type="text" placeholder="answer the question"/>
    </form>
  </div>
))}
```

Arrow functions always have the same `this` as the context of where they were defined. Other functions, however, change their `this` value depending on how they are called.